# Django filter date, where timedelta day var is equal to a model field

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to populate the timedelta param days with a model integer field but it says no defined.

```
query = POPlan.objects.filter(Q(status="INCOMPLETE") | Q(status="PARTIAL"),
  date_created__date__lte=timezone.now().date()-datetime.timedelta(days=
  (supplier__expectedDuration)))
```

The supplier field is foreign key relationship in my POPlan model and has an integer field of expected duration. Any suggestions on how to implement this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need an [`F()`-Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to reference values of other model fields. The [`ExtractDays()`-Function`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractDay) should allow you to extract the number of days from a time delta.

```py
from djano.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import F, Q, DurationField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, ExtractDay

query = POPlan.objects.filter(Q(status="INCOMPLETE") | Q(status="PARTIAL"))
query = query.annotate(
    diff=ExtractDay(Cast(timezone.now().date-F("date_created__date"), 
        output_field=DurationField()
    ))
).filter(diff__gt=F("supplier__expectedDuration"))
```

Comment: First of all thank you! I tried the solution! However i get this error : 'Extract requires native DurationField database support.'

Comment: @Andre what database are you using?

Comment: I am using a postgres !

Comment: This is strange as this is supposed to work with Postgresql.

Comment: Did you find solution @Andre?